# TensorFlow 2 Conv2D Reshape/Remap 1D Array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0, reshape, numpy-slicing

I have data coming from a C# application which I have flattened out to a 1 dimensional array and send over GRPC to tensorflow serving to a served model. Inference works so the model is structured property and tensorflow serving is working properly.

The inference data is 4,000 doubles.

The model input shape is 100, 40, 1 for the first Conv2D layer.

Training samples are 4000 doubles and a single integer label which can be 3 possible values (1,2,3 or -1,0,1 etc)

- Each feature is a size of 40 doubles.
- There are 100 features in a data sample.
- The label input is a single integer and the label/prediction result is a categorical cross entropy encoding the 3 possible values.
- Python 3 is a constraint so this can't be done in C#, only in python.

2 questions:

1. How do I reshape the training sample data in python to conform to a 100, 40 input?
2. How do I remap (also in python) single integer label to the the size 3 integer array for encoding the output?

I'm fine with trivial 1,2,3...40 integers arrays created by np.arange() for demonstration then 100 of those. I have been hacking away in a Jupyter notebooks for weeks trying to get this right with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,4001)
print(a)
print(a.shape)
a_mat = a.reshape([40, 100])
print(a_mat)
print(a.shape)
```

Second one use sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit([-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1])

print (lb.transform([-1, 0, 1]))
# [[1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0]
#  [0 0 1]]

print (lb.transform([1]))
# [[0 0 1]]
```